# My image looks different

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I'm following the blender tutorial series by the BlenderGuru and my donut looks different after tutorial #4, making the icing on the donut look more realistic. The colouring on my icing looks like it has black residue around it.

I believe it's my videocard, I'm using a 2009 macbook pro 13inch model, however, I'm new to this and trying to learn which is why I'm asking.

Attached is a screenshot of what it looks like...

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

[image]

Comment: It could be your video card, a couple things to check, make sure you dont accidentally have 2 icing's. Might have to delete one. Or try lifting the icing up just a bit, maybe it is intersecting with the bottom part.

Comment: After further inspection I discovered there was a second icing layer. I started all over again and it worked out perfectly.

Thanks again for the advice